# Is it acceptable to inherit data types from two different contracts (logic and storage?)

Tags: contract-design, inheritance, solidity-0.8.x

I am using a data separation pattern, keeping my data in a contract and the business logic in a separate contract that calls the storage one to add/update/delete records.

In order to send the Data struct as an argument in those CRUD functions, would it be acceptable to create a third "types" contract and inherit the types both from "logic" and "storage" contracts?

```
// Types.sol

contract Types {
  struct Data {
    ...attributes
  }
}
```

```
// Logic.sol

contract Logic is Types {
  function someFunction(type1 param1, type2 param2) {
    Data data = Data(param1, param2);
    storage.someFunction(data);
  }
}

// Storage.sol

contract Storage is Types {
  function someFunction(Data data) onlyLogic { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all. *Inheritance* in Solidity is essentially fake. The reality is, at compile-time, you will end up with all the functions merged in a single smart contract. It's just a way to separate code mentally. If you *extend* a contract many times (with many `is Types` in your case), Solidity adds functions from `Types` contract only once in any case.